# Creating a local mailbox for NIS account

Tags: linux, fedora

What is the way of creating a local mailbox for a user that have a NIS account, but doesn't have any local one?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by creating a local account with exactly the same login name, UID and GID that it has in NIS. This way a mail box is created for the user and after the user with NIS account logs in it has that mailbox working.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure it's directly possible. Maybe you could add the user as local with Nologin shell and that way give ham an account with mail?